# how do i automatically updated gmail hotmail or yahoo addressbook from website

Tags: php, email, gmail, hotmail, yahoo-mail

is that possible to automatically updated gmail hotmail or yahoo address book or contacts from direct website? if yes then any kind of example available?

**For Example**

```
if any customer's or user's registered with their emails then 
their emails should be automatically updated into my email 
address book or contact list?
```

Comment: Do you made a google sreach?

Comment: @Hydroid yes search on google but didn't find any kind of example to related to my question?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with the **[Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)**.

**[Good link with examples](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-phpgooglecontact/)**.

From Google Contacts API:

> To create a new contact, send an authorized POST request to the user's
>   contacts feed URL with contact data in the body.

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
```